# Rules and roles in GeoServer not working

Tags: geoserver, security

I have in a GeoServer (v2.16) two workspaces, with associated users and roles for those users.
 The file in `/opt/geoserver/data_dir/security/layers.properties` looks like this:

```
#Thu Mar 12 10:44:20 GMT 2020
mode=HIDE
*.*.w=GROUP_ADMIN,ADMIN
workspace1.*.r=ROLE1
workspace2.*.r=ROLE2
```

But still both users can see both workspaces. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

I also tried

```
#Thu Mar 12 10:44:20 GMT 2020
mode=HIDE
*.*.w=GROUP_ADMIN,ADMIN
*.*.r=GROUP_ADMIN,ADMIN
workspace1.*.r=ROLE1
workspace2.*.r=ROLE2
```

and it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

You should deny read access first, and then override it with more specialized rules (the system works by overriding the more general rule with the more specific ones):

```
#Thu Mar 12 10:44:20 GMT 2020
mode=HIDE
*.*.w=GROUP_ADMIN,ADMIN
*.*.r=GROUP_ADMIN,ADMIN
workspace1.*.r=ROLE1
workspace2.*.r=ROLE2
```

Comment: I had it like this before and it did not work, either. That's why i tried without that.

Comment: Are you sure you switched the logins properly? Like, sometimes the browsers keep cookies or cached autentication, did you repeat your tests with anonymous tabs to make sure there are not caches intervening.

Comment: Now user 1 can see both stores, but user 2 can see only store 2

Comment: Is there any other configuration that might affect this behaviour? In the workspace, or store...?